# can I update input field value with setState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-state

I'm new to React and I implemented a form which uses `Material-UI` and `react-input-mask` library. I would like to know how to change user input value in the input field.

For example, I have this field:

```
class TemplateForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state= {
    api_access: true,
    currency: "", 
    sku: "",
  }
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
}
onChange = (event) => {
    const {name, value} = event.target
    this.setState({
     [name]: value
 })
}
onSubmit = (formVals) => {
  return false;
}
renderField=({input,label, meta:{touched,error}})=> (
<InputMask mask="99/9999"
       value = {this.state.edate}
       name="edate"
       type="tel"
       required
       {...input}
>
{(inputProps) => 
  <TextField
     {...inputProps}
     label={label}
     fullWidth
  />}
</InputMask>
)

handleBlur = (value) => {
    valueM = value.split("/")
    if (valueM[0].length< 2) {
        valueM[0]= "0"+valueM[0]
    }
    valueM = valueM.join("/")
    this.setState({
       ename:valueM
    })
}
<Field id="ename" name="ename" onBlur={this.handleBlur} component={this.renderField} />
}
```

I would like to change value of the month field with a leading zero when user enters only one digit. Like if user enters `1_/2022` should be converted to `01/2022` but `this.setState()` isn't changing the value in the field. How to achieve this?

Comment: this.setState doesnt work with functional components.

Comment: @Alexander I actually have a class component

Comment: I think the issue here is, that you put the state directly into a function definition. When react creates this function, it fills in the state in that moment. After that, the function reference stays the same, and the internal variable isn't updated anymore. I'm not sure but I also think that any other method except the `render` function of the class can't be properly tracked by react.

Comment: Got it, how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide entire component?